# How to delete Whitespace from textview in the end and also delete white space from enter keys in swift2.0

Tags: swift2, ios7.1, xcode7.3

I am new to swift.I want to delete white space and also delete new line white space from TextView.So please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, You want to trim space and new line at the end of your text? or you want to show textView empty when there is no other words then white space and newline?

Comment: yes. as like stack overflow comment box. @Sahil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **new line** or when the **enter button** is pressed you can use the **delegate method**

`func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool`

add this to the method
`if  text == "\n"
        {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            return false
        }`

For whitespace in the end use the below code.

```
var stringFromText = textView.text

    var lastChar = stringFromText.characters.last


    while lastChar == " " {
        stringFromText = String(stringFromText.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))
        print(stringFromText!)
       if stringFromText != "" {
            lastChar = stringFromText?.characters.last
        }
        else
        {
            lastChar = "A" //Any random char
        }

        print(lastChar!)
    }
    textComment.text = stringFromText
```

Hope it helps.